# How can we completely remove Rust installed by Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, rust, ubuntu-18.04, uninstallation, rust-cargo

I want to update my Rust to latest but when I searched for `rustup` it was not showing up in my system `rustup: command not found`. I tried to install rustup using `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`. It gave this warning.

```
warning: rustup should not be installed alongside Rust. Please uninstall your existing Rust first.
warning: Otherwise you may have confusion unless you are careful with your PATH
warning: If you are sure that you want both rustup and your already installed Rust
warning: then please reply `y' or `yes' or set RUSTUP_INIT_SKIP_PATH_CHECK to yes
```

I tried to remove `rustc` with `sudo apt remove rustc` but it returns

```
Package 'rustc' is not installed, so not removed
```

although I can access `rustc` from terminal. My current `rustc` and `cargo` version is 1.47.0.

Comment: If you installed it with `apt install` then the problem is that it wasn't called `rustc` it was called something else. You need to search your packages for things that contain the word "rust". And `apt remove` that.

Comment: `apt list | grep rust` should only list installed packages containing the word rust.

Comment: `apt list | grep rust` shows, rust-doc, rust-gdb, rust-lldb, rust-src, rustc

Comment: I imagine `apt list --installed rust` doesn't show any packages. Which would mean that rust-doc, rust-gdb, rust-lldb, rust-src, rustc... are installed but not by apt and therefor it can't remove them.

Comment: Do you remember how you installed rustc?

Comment: my bad `apt list` was not the correct command `apt list --installed` is. This answer should be useful for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/1263517/817697

Comment: `apt list --installed|grep rust` doesn't show any rust programs same being `dpkg --list | grep -i rust` any idea how to remove rust

Comment: The only other idea I have is to manually delete it. `which rustc` should give you the path where its located. Delete everything there.

Comment: both cargo and rustc is located here `/usr/local/bin/` is it ok to delete those directories

Comment: Please don't delete `/usr/local/bin/` esp if there's other stuff in there.

Comment: sorry I ment rustc, rustfmt, cargo and cargo-clippy files, I already deleted those files

Comment: Don't delete `/usr/local/bin/`! But now that you deleted rustc and others does the `rustup` installation work?

Comment: yep I deleted all the **rustc, rustfmt, cargo and cargo-clippy** files inside `/usr/local/bin/` and reinstalled rust, now its working fine. It would be great If you can put your comments as an answer this might come useful for others.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this *without* manually deleting the old rust binaries by uninstalling cargo and then auto-removing its now un-needed dependencies:

```sh
sudo apt remove cargo
sudo apt autoremove
```

After that completes, you should be able to run the `rustup` installation script normally:

```sh
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

Remember that you may need to restart your shell or logout before your system `PATH` will be updated to include the new binaries.